# Show that the system $\dot{x}=Ax+Bu$ is controllable if the linear system of equations $XA-AX=0$, $XB=0$ admits only the trivial solution $X = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, control-theory

> Show that the system $\dot{x}=Ax+Bu$ is controllable if the linear system of equations $XA-AX=0$, $XB=0$ admits only the trivial solution $X = 0$ .

(The system is controllable iff the controllability matrix $[B, AB, A^{2}B, ..., A^{n-1}B]$ has full row rank)

Comment: Can you state what it means for the system to be controllable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note, this is not a complete answer**: I don't know if this is related because I almost have no intuitive understanding of ranks but from the first equation we see that $X$ and $A$ commute. If we multiply the first equation by $B$ from the right we will obtain:

$$
X\,A\,B - A\,X\,B = 0 \implies X\,A\,B = 0.
$$

Then multiply from the left with $A$ and then use that $X$ and $A$ commute successively and write down the following equations:

$$
\begin{array}{c}
X\,B = 0 \\
X\,A\,B = 0 \\
X\,A^2B = 0 \\
\vdots \\
X\,A^{n-1}B = 0
\end{array}
$$

Or written as matrix

$$
X \begin{bmatrix}B & A\,B & A^2B & \cdots & A^{n-1}B \end{bmatrix}=0.
$$

Now knowing only little about the rank I would guess that the last equation implies what we are looking for, as it is similar to the case of an invertible matrix (which is square and has full rank). Hence, I would guess that if $X=0$ is the only solution to this equation then the system is controllable because the controllability matrix has to have full rank (similar to the invertible matrix).

Like I told this is just an attempt to solve this problem. We will have to wait for someone who is able to judge if this is a valid procedure.

Comment: oh, this makes sense to me! So for the last step, let's call $[B AB ... A^{n-1}B]$ for $C$, then $XC=0$. For the system to be controllable, $C$ has to be invertable. If $C$ is invertable, then $X = XCC^{-1}= 0*C^{-1} =0$. Would this be sufficient as proof or am I missing something?

Comment: No, note that the controllability matrix is in general not a square matrix, hence it cannot have an inverse. But if $C$ was square then showing this would be easier. But I think it is the same with the rank of an equation. If $XC=0$ is only true for $X=0$ then $C$ must have full rank. That is what we need to show.

Comment: Assuming that $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ we do know that the controllability matrix (I will denote it with $\mathcal{C}$) lies in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n\,m}$. So if $(A,B)$ is controllable, then $\mathcal{C}\,\mathcal{C}^\top$ should be non-singular (invertible). But I do not think that you need this, because your last equation can only have a non-zero solution for $X$ if $\mathcal{C}$ does not have full column rank (so when the columns of $\mathcal{C}$ do not span the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$). But the column and row rank of a non-square matrix are the same.